# Name of a Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Can I ask for help on something that has me really puzzled? I have written a small function to demonstrate:

```cs
void Test()
{
    CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
    string temp = checkBox1.Name;
}
```

`temp` is an empty string after this has run. Since "checkBox1" is not the Name of the control what is it?

Comment: See [Control.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-control-name): *The name of the control. The default is an empty string ("").* `checkBox1`is the variable name of your CheckBox instance.

Comment: So try new CheckBox { Name = "Something" }

Comment: `checkBox1.Name` is a property and it can contain what you want.
If you look at the designer file of a form where you created a checkbox with the graphical editor, you'll see that the `Name` property is explicitly assigned with a string corresponding to the object name. But that string can be what you want. If you don't assign it, it will be empty.

Comment: The string assigned to a Control's `Name` Property, at design-time, comes from the Control's Designer; it reflects the name of the Field used to reference the Control's instance. When you create a Control at run-time, you most probably don't need to set the `Name`, you just handle the instance (`checkBox1`, here) you have created. Depending on how this instance is handled, not don't even need the instance name (e.g., when you just need to get the Control's instance in an event handler, since the `sender` object holds that reference)

Comment: If your Wallet is empty, and you put nothing into it. Then you pick it up, it is still empty. Place something into it and there - you have something. did you put control name into the Name property?

Answer (score 1):

**checkBox1** is a variable name or an instance name of the CheckBox class, e.g. I have a pet dog (class), its name is Benji (variable name).

**.Name** is a property of this CheckBox control, a piece of information you can store in this control. See [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the `Name` property of the `CheckBox` will have no value until one is assigned. In addition, I would recommend using the `nameof` keyword in this context. This way, if you refactor the variable itself to something other than `checkBox1` then the `Name` property will follow the new name.

This code snippet in the MainForm class adds a checkbox. If you look at the `temp` variable now, it should contain the expected value.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox
    {
        Name = nameof(checkBox1),
        Text = "Example",
        Location = new Point(10,10),
    };
    Controls.Add(checkBox1);

    string temp = checkBox1.Name;
}
```

[image: Programmatically added checkbox on the main form.]